# Removed parent category path - New URL's not showing up in Google search results

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite, indexing, reindex

Last month we removed parent category path from the sub category URL's. After that we changed the sitemap file with new URL's and submit it to the webmaster tools for indexing.

For Ex: www.example.com/sub1/sub2 has been changed to www.example.com/sub2

The problem is still the new URL's are not getting indexed by Google. I have done everything like removing breadcrumbs and used "Fetch as Google" option for re-crawling, but nothing worked.

Can anyone please tell me a solution for this issue.

Comment: Hi, i think you should ask this question on webmasters.stackexchange.com. It doesn't se to be specific to magento. The index and the reindex tag you used refer to the internal magento indexing system, not to the Google index.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you could check. First of all, what do the URLs in the sitemap look like? Do they have the new URL paths? If not, you might have to regenerate your sitemaps and check again.

Next up, check if the sitemap is imported correctly, which will probably be the case.

Apart from that, you should enable the canonical URLs, so search engines will only have one path to index, even when it's coming in from an incorrect path. You can check if the canonical URLs are enabled by opening a category or product page and check the meta tags. If there is no canonical there, you can easily enable it by going to **System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog** and then look under the **Search Engine Optimisations** tab for the options **Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories** and **Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products**. Make sure they're both set to "Yes". The canonical URLs make sure search engines will only index those URLs, no matter what the URL is it will use to show the page.

And last but not least, make sure you have redirects from the old URLs to the new URLs, so everyone (search engines and visitors) are redirected to the correct URL.